# Configuring Chrome logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, rspec, capybara

I am trying to debug some rspec tests that just hang at random without any apparent reason (Rails 6.1 Ruby 3 Rspec 4 Capybara), so I need access to Chrome logs so I can spend another 2 weeks looking for possible errors/problems.

Chrome is currently logging under `/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.<random>/Default/chrome_debug.log` (for some reason the datadir isn't ~/.chrome but goes under /tmp).

I'd like to get them to save under `/app/log/chrome.log` but for some reason none of the documented parameters work.

Based on the 1390745 possibilities people wrote about, I have tried:

```
--log-path=/app/log
--log-path=/app/log/chrome.log
--log-path=stdout
--log-file=/app/log/chrome.log
--log-file=stdout
--enable-logging=/app/log
--enable-logging=/app/log/chrome.log
--enable-logging=stdout
```

No luck, at most it disabled logging completely, despite the path being accessible and 777'ed.

Does anyone know how to get Chrome to log to a specific file?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the hanging specs? if so, I would try to run the tests using a non-headless browser configuration, so you can see what's going on. If you can find some pattern on where the tests are hanging you should be able to also add some logging in your code (you can print things in the logs but also take screenshots and save the current html at any moment during the tests with save_screenshot and save_page) It doesn't sound like chrome logs will have all the information you need to debug that

Comment: No I am not able to reproduce or see a pattern. Random feature tests fail at random. The browser just hangs, there's no error or anything like that in the console.